# change relationship between tables in crystal reports after creating it

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report and imported 3 tables and also set relationship between them using **Standard Report Creation Wizard**. Now I want to change relationship between tables. But how can I change it? (e.g. how to start **Standard Report Creation Wizard** again?)

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted this. It's a legit question. And online documentation for Crystal is pretty poor, so usually I'd rather get Crystal answers from SO where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Database | Database Expert...` to

- adding and removing tables
- changing table names
- modifying linkage
- creating a Command (a 'raw' SQL statement)

`Database | Set Location...` to:

- change the data source (change from one database instance to another) for main and subreports
- see the details of each table's connection

Answer (score 0):

You use the Database Expert to do this. The place where you do this is easy to miss. There's another tab in the Database Expert that lets you view/modify links.

It's here:

[image: Crystal Reports Database Expert screenshot]